# How do I add passengers to entity in minecraft 1.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Not summon but add so I tried

> /entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand] {Passengers:[{id:Cow}]}

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this directly for pre-existing entities. `Passengers` (and `Riding` before it) is only parsed when the mob is loaded/spawned. The `/entitydata` command does not have access to this functionality.

---

`Passengers` is not actually a valid tag for entity NBT merging/creation via commands. Instead, the `/summon` command manually checks if you specified a list tag named "Passengers" in your input to handle instantiating new entities, while the remainder of your input is handled automatically by the target entity's NBT-reading functions. The `/entitydata` command itself makes no use of the tag, so it is essentially ignored as the NBT-reading functions from the entity classes will not read that tag.

#### /summon

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Cow"}],IsBaby:1b}
```

The `CommandSummon` class looks for the "Passengers" tag, finds it, and instantiates the new entity. All the input data is then sent to the `EntityZombie` class, which finds that `IsBaby` is a valid tag but does **not** find that `Passengers` is a valid tag (hence it being ignored).

#### /entitydata

```
/entitydata @e[type=Zombie] {Passengers:[{id:"Cow"}],IsBaby:0b}
```

The `CommandEntityData` class does **not** look for the "Passengers" tag. The input data (after merging with the zombie's pre-existing data) is sent to the same NBT-reading function in the `EntityZombie` class that `/summon` was sending its data to. Same as before, it finds `IsBaby` is valid while `Passengers` is invalid.

The reason you see `Passengers` in the command's last output data is because it shows you what it was provided *before* verification. If the entity already had passengers and you did not try to change them, it's because the output shown is taken from the NBT-*writing* function (used for storing entities to chunk files), which does write the host's passengers into a `Passengers` list. But since the NBT-reading functions do not look for this tag, it will be ignored even in that case.

---

You will instead need to create a new entity and delete the old one.

```
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand]
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Cow"}]}
```

Comment: I'm amazed at your knowledge of the inner workings of Minecraft. Are you reading the code yourself?

Comment: @MrLemon Aye, I use [MCP](http://www.modcoderpack.com/website/releases) for a deobfuscated look into 1.8 and then decompile the snapshot jars myself and compare them. It can get tricky since the snapshots are obfuscated, but in this case there's not too much changed between 1.8 and 1.9 for the `/summon` command's class. The functionality for "Riding" (now "Passengers") was moved out of the command's class (along with entity class instantiation itself) to the chunk loader class, so is now more accessible/consolidated, but the concept of how the tag worked related to commands remained the same.